# In-memory database tests not creating tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I have test class annotated with these:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties={"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
```

These is HSQLDB in Maven dependencies so it is tried to be used during the tests cause of @AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation. However tables are not created, Hibernate instead is just validating that tables are not found. Writing property value into application.properties does not change anything. I remember when I was developing at some moment it worked few times for me, but I did not notice what special/different I was doing that time. Is there anything else to do/check or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this annotations to your test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {<your start class>.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

p.s. don't forget to replace  to your start class.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: By now, I had to update code with more dependencies, bringing Qpid which by itself brought Derby database, and now auto creating tables works as expected, without changes to "classes" variable. Will try to bring back HSQLDB to see if things will be bad again.

Comment: Now added Derby to exclusions so HSQLDB is used again, and it is still working without change to "classes". So, there is something different happening behind the scenes.